# Ember data django rest adapter authorization jwt

Tags: ember.js, django-rest-framework, jwt

i'm using ember-simple-auth and ember-simple-auth-token to implement a client side session mechanism. My backend is writtend in django(DRF + DRF jwt) and I'm using ember-django-adapter. I defined a route users, a model user but when i try to go to http://myhost/users i have this error:

```
Error while processing route: users.index Authentication credentials were not provided. Error: Authentication credentials were not provided.
```

How can i tell to ember django adapter to add a specific authorization token(grabbed from ember-simpe-auth session) when making an http request?

Thank You.

PS:  i added to config\environment.js this code

```
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:token'
};

ENV['simple-auth-token'] = {
  serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://myhost/api/jwt-auth/',
  identificationField: 'username',
  tokenPropertyName: 'token',
  authorizationPrefix: 'JWT',
  authorizationHeaderName: 'Authorization',
};
```

Comment: I did not read this in ember-simple-auth docs https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth#cross-origin-authorization and I didn't add my backend to crossOriginWhilelist